# Find a multiple word with number into a text file

Tags: python, find, extract, cpu-word

I have a text file ( they called intxt.txt). In this file there are words and numbers. I need to write in  "outtxt"  the word followed by number or line found.

the interessed words are:

- "MSG" and the rest of line found
- S only followed by numbers found
- F only followed by numbers found

They must be write into a outtxt file in a order of search

---

intxt.txt file:

hi there is a multiple name:
S5000
F8000 AND THE REST OF
IN THE REST OF MACHINE TOOL THERE IS
A MSG("UTILIZZARE QUESTO MESSAGGIO DA ESTRARRE")
I TRY TO CHOOSE
S9000 F5000"

---

Expected result:

S5000

F8000

MSG("UTILIZZARE QUESTO MESSAGGIO DA ESTRARRE")

S9000 F5000

---

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python
from    tkinter.ttk import  Combobox
from    tkinter import  ttk
from    tkinter.filedialog  import  askopenfilename
import  os
import  re
import time
from pathlib import Path
from    tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames
from    tkinter import  *

window=Tk()

var=IntVar()

def OpenFile():
    filename    =   askopenfilenames(initialdir="",#se   non specificato va  su  quella  di              default per l'account
                                filetypes   =(("Text File","*.txt"),("Text File","*.MPF"),("Text File","*.H"),("Text File","*"),("All Files","*.*")), #estensione di  ricerca file
                                title   =   "Seleziona file") 
    for filename  in filename:                            
     with    open(filename)  as  intxt:
        name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]+'_.txt'
        with    open(name,  'w')    as  outtxt:
                name1= Path(filename).stem
                outtxt.write("list: "+name1+"   "+ time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"+"  %H:%M:%S"))
                outtxt.write('\n')
                outtxt.write('\n')

                offset=(re.findall('(MSG[ ("a-zA-Z ].*)\d*.*'and'S\d+'and'F\d+',intxt.read()))
                outtxt.write("\n".join(offset))
            
            
                          
#FINE   COMANDO OPEN    FILE

#INZIO  PULSANTE    OPEN    FILE
btn=Button(window,  text="Apri",    fg='black', command=    OpenFile)
btn.place(x=100,    y=100)
#FINE   PULSANTE    OPEN    FILE

window.title('Estra')
window.geometry("300x300+10+10")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a regex, you can use:

```
\bMSG.*|[SF]\d+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bMSG.*` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, then match MSG and the rest of the line
- `|` Or
- `[SF]\d+` Match either `S` or `F` followed by 1 or more digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IDG8dv/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NQ6TGo)

```
import re

pattern = r"\bMSG.*|[SF]\d+"

s = ("hi there is a multiple name:\n"
    "S5000\n"
    "F8000 AND THE REST OF\n"
    "IN THE REST OF MACHINE TOOL THERE IS \n"
    "A MSG(\"UTILIZZARE QUESTO MESSAGGIO DA ESTRARRE\")\n"
    "I TRY TO CHOOSE\n"
    "S9000 F5000\"")
offset = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(offset)
```

)

Output

```
['S5000', 'F8000', 'MSG("UTILIZZARE QUESTO MESSAGGIO DA ESTRARRE")', 'S9000', 'F5000']
```